# Can I install wireless drivers from exe file?

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have a Lenovo z50-70. I've recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I can't install my wireless drivers because the website only has EXE files (http://goo.gl/e00jkG).

I also have to install the Nvidia Geforce drivers since it has 2gb ram dedicated to graphics but those are not as important.

Than you.

Comment: For wireless drivers from `exe`, you need to follow this [Ubuntu Doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper). It details the `NDISWrapper` which is used to install wireless drivers from an `exe`.

For latest NVIDIA drivers, follow this [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZ-r3gS38RU).

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more details. No you cannot install .exe files into Linux.

```
uname -r
dmesg | grep iwl
```

You can get the drivers from this location

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi

If ubuntu desktop 14.0.4 is not very much required for you - i will suggest go ahead and install ubuntu desktop 15.10 it will solve most of the wifi problems.

regarding nvidia drivers, follow these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot 

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
sudo reboot
```

Comment: However, the page he linked suggested he may have either an Intel or an Atheros wireless device. I suggest you edit your answer to ask for `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`